PGVectorscale: failure to create index SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: assertion failed: meta_page.get_num_dimensions_to_index() > 0 && <= 2000
I'm building a prototype ML system using Postgres-based extension vectorscale. It goes as follows:
I use a docker image timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg17

I've created a table for embeddings:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products.products_embedding (
embedding_id int8 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"text" varchar(255),
embedding vector(3072),
metadata json
);

I've installed a vectorscale extension:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS vectorscale CASCADE;


That all works well and I can see the extension created:
SELECT * 
FROM pg_extension; - that lists my `vectorscale` extension

Now, as per documentation, when I attempt to creatre an index, as in:
CREATE INDEX argos_products_embedding_idx ON products.products_embedding 
USING diskann (embedding) WITH(num_neighbors=20);

, that blows in my face with the following error:
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: assertion failed: meta_page.get_num_dimensions_to_index() > 0 && meta_page.get_num_dimensions_to_index() <= 2000
I tried all sort of values for num_neighbours between 10 and 100, still getting the same error.
Any help please?
And the bigger question is: vector search on PgVector is rater slow, so I tried to speed that up using an index. Any better ideas on how to achive that than using what I'm doing?

That is probably a bug in the extension, and you should report it as such.
